# Echo data from SQL table column into HTML row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this Laravel code to retrieve data from database:

```
$stats = DB::table('jobRequirements')
    ->join('jobs', 'jobRequirements.job', '=', 'jobs.id')
    ->join('types', 'jobRequirements.type', '=', 'types.id')
    ->join('users', 'jobs.user', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('users.name as user, SUM(jobRequirements.number) as number, types.name as type'))
    ->where('jobRequirements.active', 1)
    ->groupBy('types.id')
    ->orderBy('users.name'asc')
    ->get();

return view('stats',compact('stats'));
```

Then I display it in table with Laravel blade like this:

```
@foreach($stats as $s)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$s->user}}</td>   
    <td>{{$s->number}}</td>
    <td>{{$s->type}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

With that I get this:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}



<table>
  <tr>
    <td>User1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Type2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Type3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Type1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User4</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Type3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User4</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Type6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I need it like this:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}



<table>
  <tr>
    <td>User name</td>
    <td>Type1</td>
    <td>Type2</td>
    <td>Type3</td>
    <td>Type6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I achieve that?

I don't need complete solution, some examples or directions would be nice. It can be in plain PHP also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions:

1. Fix your query so you can get something like this (I assume your types are fixed?!)
   SELECT username, number of type1, number of type2, number of type3, number of type 6
2. Before return view(..) in your controller store your data in this format:

[username] = ['type1' = a number, 'type2' => a number', 'type3' => a number', 'type7' => a number']

```
$data = array();
// foreach row
foreach ($stats as $key => $value) {
    // if user doesn't exist in the array
    if (!array_key_exists($value->user, $data))  {
        // Add the user to the array
        $data[$value->user] = array('type1' => 0, 'type2' => 0, 'type3' => 0, 'type6' => 0);
    }
    // Add the number of the type to the corresponded type
    // Optional: You can do a check before adding if the type is already added
    $data[$value->user][$value->type] = $value->number;
}
```

And **pass $data** to your view and in the view you do:

```
@foreach($stats as $key => $value)
<tr>
<td>{{$key}}</td>
<td>{{$value['type1']}}</td>
<td>{{$value['type2']}}</td>
<td>{{$value['type3']}}</td>
<td>{{$value['type7']}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I hope I could help you a bit.

Comment: with some modification it works like this, only problem is that types are not fixed but this is good starting point for me

Comment: How many types are there? Are you gonna show all the types in the table regardless if it has a value for a user or not?

Comment: Its dynamic number of types, they can be added and deleted. I want to show just types that have value (for one user at least)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach($stats as $key => $s){
   $user .= '<td>'.$s->user.'</td>';
   $number .= '<td>'.$s->number.'</td>';
   $type .= '<td>'.$s->type.'</td>';
 }
```

To print table,

```
<table>     
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><b>User</b></td>{{ $user }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Number</b></td>{{ $number }}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Type</b></td>{{ $type }}
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: hmm with this I am getting same result only in horizontal view.. users are still not grouped and first column is empty but it should contain users name